# jQuery Cloned django-selectable Autocomplete Dropdowns Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, autocomplete

As the title states, I have a django-selectable autocomplete form field on my page, that I am trying to clone dynamically after page load. The cloning part works, but the autocomplete fields do not function. I don't know the internals of django-selectable, and I'm still learning jQuery so I am lost as far as figuring out how to "fix" the autoselect functionality.

My general approach is this: I render the form widget using django template variable inside a div container, and I clone the div container.

HTML

```
<div class="autocomplete" id="autocomplete_{{ form.instance.id}}">{{form.autocomplete_dropdown}}</div>
```

jQuery

```
// This works, just the cloned form lacks "autocomplete" functionality.
var autocompleteArray = theDiv.find('.autocomplete');
var acClone = autocompleteArray.clone();
table.find(".column").append(acClone);
```

[image: Screenshot of dynamically cloned autocomplete forms]
Based on SunnySydeUp's comments I made the following revisions:

jQuery

```
// Clone the div and all its contents
var acClone = autocompleteArray.clone(true, true);
// Get the children of the div
var acCloneChildrenArray = acClone.children();
// iterate through the children array, modify ids where they exist to make them unique
// e.g., unique id contained in idSuffix.
for (var i = 0; i < acCloneChildrenArray.length; i++) {
    // if it has an id, make it unique
    if (acCloneChildrenArray[i].getAttribute('id')) {
        var ident = acCloneChildrenArray[i].getAttribute('id')
        acCloneChildrenArray[i].setAttribute('id', ident+'_'+idSuffix);
    };
};
```

Now the data and events are copied, but they are tied to the prototype/master dropdown. That is, clicking one of the cloned objects actually triggers the dropdown for the master. I guess the question comes down to how to attach the event handler dynamically to the new dropdowns?

Final working code (has a minor bug--duplicated dropdown button, but the autocomplete and dropdown functionality works, per SunnySydeUp's solution).

jQuery

```
// Clone the div
// We leave clone deepcopy flags at default==false
var acClone = autocompleteArray.clone();

// Get the children of the div
// You don't need to set unique id's on the children, it's irrelevant.

// Bind the new selectable fields to the event handlers.
window.bindSelectables('body');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `django-selectable` before but I'm guessing it uses javascript/jQuery to make the autocomplete work. When you call `clone`, it doesn't clone the javascript for the dropdown. Try doing:

```
var acClone = autocompleteArray.clone(true);
```

Passing in true will make jQuery also copy the data and events on that input.

[Clone documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: Thank you SunnySydeUp. I have made revisions to my code based on your feedback. You are on the right track, but now the events need to be tied to the cloned dropdowns. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: After a quick glance at django-selectable's javascript source (jquery.dj.selectable.js), it seems like it's doing `window.bindSelectables('body');`. Maybe give that a try?

Comment: Yes! That works with minor modification: you have to set the deepcopy flag to false for .clone(). There's a minor bug (a duplicated dropdown button for each form, but the autocomplete and dropdown functionality is there. Thank you so much. I tried about 20 different things, overall trying to get this to work.